# Creation timestamp and last update timestamp with Hibernate and MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp

For a certain Hibernate entity we have a requirement to store its creation time and the last time it was updated.  How would you design this?

- What data types would you use in the database (assuming MySQL, possibly in a different timezone that the JVM)?  Will the data types be timezone-aware?
- What data types would you use in Java (`Date`, `Calendar`, `long`, ...)?
- Whom would you make responsible for setting the timestamps—the database, the ORM framework (Hibernate), or the application programmer?
- What annotations would you use for the mapping (e.g. `@Temporal`)?

I'm not only looking for a working solution, but for a safe and well-designed solution.

Comment: I think it's better to use LocalDateTime instead of outdated Date in Java entities. Also, db should not be aware about time zone, it causing many problems with data migration. So I would use datetime SQL type.

Answer (score 310):

If you are using the JPA annotations, you can use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` event hooks do this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entities")    
public class Entity {
  ...

  private Date created;
  private Date updated;

  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    created = new Date();
  }

  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    updated = new Date();
  }
}
```

or you can use the `@EntityListener` annotation on the class and place the event code in an external class.

Comment: Works without any problems in J2SE, as @PrePersist and @PerUpdate are JPA annotations.

Comment: @Kumar - In case you are using plain Hibernate session ( instead of JPA) you can try hibernate event listeners, although that's not very elegant and compact vs JPA annotations.

Comment: In current Hibernate with JPA one can use "@CreationTimestamp" and "@UpdateTimestamp"

Comment: @FlorianLoch is there an equivalent for Date rather than Timestamp? Or would I have to create my own?

Comment: Is there a newer way to do this? (Spring Boot 3)

Answer (score 250):

You can just use `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp`:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "create_date")
private Date createDate;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "modify_date")
private Date modifyDate;
```

Comment: thanks bro such a small thing need to update timestamp. I didnt know. you saved my day.

Comment: There is `TemporalType.DATE` in the first case and `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` in the second one.

Comment: Are you saying this also automatically sets the values? That's not my experience; it seems even with `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` one either needs some `@Column(..., columnDefinition = "timestamp default current_timestamp")`, or use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` (the latter also nicely ensuring clients cannot set a different value).

Comment: Yeah, Hibernate sets it for you, don't set it manually. timestamp default current_timestamp - not needed

Comment: Why is not this the most voted answer? Any drawbacks with this?

Comment: I can answer - actually I posted it recently, and it was not well known feature. I found it maybe a year ago, just browsing all Hibernate annotations. There are a lot of useful annotations in org.hibernate.annotations package, like '@Loader', '@Where', '@Subselect', and so on.

Comment: There are no drawbacks, except that you can't use java 8 time API with it before Hibernate 5.2.3, for that purpose you can use Spring Data '@LastModifiedDate' and '@CreatedDate'

Comment: In my case, the DB column (created_date) didn't have a default value and it was nullable, so in my case, i had to do @Column(name = "create_date" , nullable=false) for it to work, but this was a push in the right direction for me :) thank you !

Comment: When I update the object and persist it, the bd lost the create_date... why?

Comment: Im my case removing `nullable=false` from `@Column(name = "create_date" , nullable=false)` worked

Comment: @BrennoLeal Same here, an update is removing creation date even I applied nullable = false. using <hibernate.version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate.version>

Comment: @Max I'm having the same issue. Were you able to fix it in the meantime?

Comment: @Tomasulo , use  @Column(name = "creation_date", updatable = false)

Comment: Just add `updatable=false` to createdDate not for modifyDate like `@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "create_date", updatable=false)
private Date createDate]`

Comment: I found when using the timestamps I always have to add the following annotation to the class to make them function properly:
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

Answer (score 123):

Taking the resources in this post along with information taken left and right from different sources, I came with this elegant solution, create the following abstract class

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractTimestampEntity {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private Date created;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated", nullable = false)
    private Date updated;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        updated = created = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updated = new Date();
    }
}
```

and have all your entities extend it, for instance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign")
public class Campaign extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is good until you want to add _different_ exclusive behaviours to your entities (and you can't extend more than one base class). afaik the only way to obtain the same effect without a base class is though aspectj itd or event listeners see @kieren dixon answer

Comment: I would do this using a MySQL trigger so that even if the full entity is not saved or is modified by any external application or manual query, it'll still update these fields.

Comment: can you give me any working example because I'm experiencing exception `not-null property references a null or transient value: package.path.ClassName.created`

Comment: @rishiAgar, No I haven't. But for now I have assign date to my property from default constructor. Will let you know once I found.

Comment: Change it to `@Column(name = "updated", nullable = false, insertable = false)` to make it work. Interesting that this answer got so many upvotes ..

Comment: Looks like an implementation change from the answer published in 2010 and your comment which came 5 years later. On a sidenote, I don't understand what "insertable = false" has to do here.

Comment: insertable="false" doesn't set values while persisting in this case, so the OP is right in his example

Answer (score 99):

1. What database column types you should use

---

Your first question was:

> What data types would you use in the database (assuming MySQL, possibly in a different timezone that the JVM)? Will the data types be timezone-aware?

In MySQL, the `TIMESTAMP` column type does a shifting from the JDBC driver local time zone to the database timezone, but it can only store timestamps up to `2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999`, so it's not the best choice for the future.

So, better to use `DATETIME` instead, which doesn't have this upper boundary limitation. However, `DATETIME` is not timezone aware. So, for this reason, it's best to use UTC on the database side and use the `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` Hibernate property.

2. What entity property type you should use

---

Your second question was:

> What data types would you use in Java (Date, Calendar, long, ...)?

On the Java side, you can use the Java 8 `LocalDateTime`. You can also use the legacy `Date`, but the Java 8 Date/Time types are better since they are immutable, and don't do a timezone shifting to local timezone when logging them.

Now, we can also answer this question:

> What annotations would you use for the mapping (e.g. `@Temporal`)?

If you are using the `LocalDateTime` or `java.sql.Timestamp` to map a timestamp entity property, then you don't need to use `@Temporal` since HIbernate already knows that this property is to be saved as a JDBC Timestamp.

Only if you are using `java.util.Date`, you need to specify the `@Temporal` annotation, like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_on")
private Date createdOn;
```

But, it's much better if you map it like this:

```
@Column(name = "created_on")
private LocalDateTime createdOn;
```

### How to generate the audit column values

Your third question was:

> Whom would you make responsible for setting the timestamps—the database, the ORM framework (Hibernate), or the application programmer?
>
> What annotations would you use for the mapping (e.g. @Temporal)?

There are many ways you can achieve this goal. You can allow the database to do that..

For the `create_on` column, you could use a `DEFAULT` DDL constraint, like :

```
ALTER TABLE post 
ADD CONSTRAINT created_on_default 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FOR created_on;
```

For the `updated_on` column, you could use a DB trigger to set the column value with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` every time a given row is modified.

Or, use JPA or Hibernate to set those.

Let's assume you have the following database tables:

[image: Database tables with audit columns]

And, each table has columns like:

- `created_by`
- `created_on`
- `updated_by`
- `updated_on`

### Using Hibernate `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` annotations

Hibernate offers the `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` annotations that can be used to map the `created_on` and `updated_on` columns.

You can use `@MappedSuperclass` to define a base class that will be extended by all entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
 
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;
 
    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
 
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

And, all entities will extend the `BaseEntity`, like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post extend BaseEntity {
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
 
    @OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private PostDetails details;
 
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "post_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "post_id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "tag_id"
        )
    )
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

However, even if the `createdOn` and `updateOn` properties are set by the Hibernate-specific `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` annotations, the `createdBy` and `updatedBy` require registering an application callback, as illustrated by the following JPA solution.

### Using JPA `@EntityListeners`

You can encapsulate the audit properties in an Embeddable:

```
@Embeddable
public class Audit {
 
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
 
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;
 
    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
 
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

And, create an `AuditListener` to set the audit properties:

```
public class AuditListener {
 
    @PrePersist
    public void setCreatedOn(Auditable auditable) {
        Audit audit = auditable.getAudit();
 
        if(audit == null) {
            audit = new Audit();
            auditable.setAudit(audit);
        }
 
        audit.setCreatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
        audit.setCreatedBy(LoggedUser.get());
    }
 
    @PreUpdate
    public void setUpdatedOn(Auditable auditable) {
        Audit audit = auditable.getAudit();
 
        audit.setUpdatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
        audit.setUpdatedBy(LoggedUser.get());
    }
}
```

To register the `AuditListener`, you can use the `@EntityListeners` JPA annotation:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
public class Post implements Auditable {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @Embedded
    private Audit audit;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
 
    @OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private PostDetails details;
 
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "post_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "post_id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "tag_id"
        )
    )
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: Very thorough answer, thanks. I disagree about preferring `datetime` over `timestamp`. You want your database to know the time zone of your timestamps. This prevents time zone conversion errors.

Comment: The `timestsmp` type does not store timezone info. It just does a conversation from app TZ to DB TZ. In reality, you want to store the client TZ separately and do the conversation in the application prior to rendering the UI.

Comment: Correct. MySQL `timestamp` is always in UTC. *MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.* [MySQL documentation: The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed and very clear answer! Although, I'd like to use the JPA embeddable class but is it possible if my tables have different column names for the createdBy and createdOn... Is it possible to specify the column names in the class that uses the embeddable class?

Comment: Yes, of course, Use `@AttributeOverride` for that.

Answer (score 21):

With Olivier's solution, during update statements you may run into:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'created' cannot be null

To solve this, add updatable=false to the @Column annotation of "created" attribute:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created", nullable = false, updatable=false)
private Date created;
```

Comment: We are using `@Version`. When an entity is set two calls are made one is to save and another one to update. I was facing the same issue because of this. Once I added `@Column(updatable = false)` it solved my problem.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use an interceptor to set the values

Create an interface called TimeStamped which your entities implement

```
public interface TimeStamped {
    public Date getCreatedDate();
    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate);
    public Date getLastUpdated();
    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdatedDate);
}
```

Define the interceptor

```
public class TimeStampInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, 
            Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        if (entity instanceof TimeStamped) {
            int indexOf = ArrayUtils.indexOf(propertyNames, "lastUpdated");
            currentState[indexOf] = new Date();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, 
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
            if (entity instanceof TimeStamped) {
                int indexOf = ArrayUtils.indexOf(propertyNames, "createdDate");
                state[indexOf] = new Date();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
}
```

And register it with the session factory

Comment: This is one solution, if you work with SessionFactory instead of EntityManager!

Comment: Just for those, who suffer with a similar problem as I did in this context: if your entity does not itself define these extra fields (createdAt, ...) but inherit it from a parent class, then this parent class has to be annotated with @MappedSuperclass - otherwise Hibernate doesn't find these fields.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks everyone who helped.  After doing some research myself (I'm the guy who asked the question), here is what I found to make sense most:

- Database column type: the timezone-agnostic number of milliseconds since 1970 represented as **`decimal(20)`** because 2^64 has 20 digits and disk space is cheap; let's be straightforward.  Also, I will use neither `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, nor triggers.  I want no magic in the DB.
- Java field type: **`long`**.  The Unix timestamp is well supported across various libs, `long` has no Y2038 problems, timestamp arithmetic is fast and easy (mainly operator `<` and operator `+`, assuming no days/months/years are involved in the calculations).  And, most importantly, both primitive `long`s and `java.lang.Long`s are **immutable**—effectively passed by value—unlike `java.util.Date`s; I'd be really pissed off to find something like `foo.getLastUpdate().setTime(System.currentTimeMillis())` when debugging somebody else's code.
- The ORM framework should be responsible for filling in the data automatically.
- I haven't tested this yet, but only looking at the docs I assume that **`@Temporal`** will do the job; not sure about whether I might use `@Version` for this purpose.  **`@PrePersist`** and **`@PreUpdate`** are good alternatives to control that manually.  Adding that to the layer supertype (common base class) for all entities, is a cute idea provided that you really want timestamping for *all* of your entities.

Comment: While longs and Longs may be immutable, that will not help you in the situation you describe.  They can still say foo.setLastUpdate(new Long(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: That's fine.  Hibernate requires the setter anyway (or it will try to access the field directly through reflection).  I was talking about difficulty chasing down who's modifying the timestamp from our application code.  It is tricky when you can do that using a getter.

Comment: I agree with your claim that the ORM framework should be responsible for filling the date automatically, but I would go one step farther and say that the date should be set from the clock of the database server, rather than the client. I'm not clear if this accomplishes this goal. In sql, I can do this by using the sysdate function, but I don't know how to do this in Hibernate or any JPA implementation.

Comment: _I want no magic in the DB._ I see what you mean, but I like to consider the fact that database should protect itself from bad/new/clueless developers. Data integrity is very important in a large company, you can't rely on others to insert good data. Constraints, defaults, and FKs will help achieve that.

Answer (score 10):

For those whose want created or modified user detail along with the time using JPA and Spring Data can follow this. You can add  `@CreatedDate`,`@LastModifiedDate`,`@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` in the base domain. Mark the base domain with `@MappedSuperclass` and `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` like shown below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class BaseDomain implements Serializable {

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdOn;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedOn;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;

}
```

Since we marked the base domain with `AuditingEntityListener` we can tell JPA about currently logged in user. So we need to provide an implementation of AuditorAware and override `getCurrentAuditor()` method. And inside `getCurrentAuditor()` we need to return the currently authorized user Id.

```
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {
    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authentication == null ? Optional.empty() : Optional.ofNullable(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

In the above code if `Optional` is not working you may using Java 7 or older. In that case try changing `Optional` with `String`.

Now for enabling the above Audtior implementation use the code below

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class JpaConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}
```

Now you can extend the `BaseDomain` class to all of your entity class where you want the created and modified date & time along with user Id

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using the Session API the PrePersist and PreUpdate callbacks won't work according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133629).

I am using Hibernate Session's persist() method in my code so the only way I could make this work was with the code below and following this [blog post](http://notatube.blogspot.ro/2010/03/hibernate-using-event-listener-to-set.html) (also posted in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133629)).

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractTimestampEntity {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created")
    private Date created=new Date();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated")
    @Version
    private Date updated;

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should return cloned objects like `updated.clone()` otherwise other components can manipulate the internal state (date)

Answer (score 4):

Now there is also @CreatedDate and @LastModifiedDate annotations.

=> https://programmingmitra.blogspot.fr/2017/02/automatic-spring-data-jpa-auditing-saving-CreatedBy-createddate-lastmodifiedby-lastmodifieddate-automatically.html

(Spring framework)

Answer (score 4):

Following code worked for me.

```
package com.my.backend.models;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter @Setter
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    protected Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    protected Date updatedAt;
}
```

Comment: Hi, why would we need `protected Integer id;` as `protected` in parent class in general, because i could not use it in my test cases as `.getId()`

Answer (score 4):

If we are using **@Transactional** in our methods, @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp will save the value in DB but will return null after using save(...).

In this situation, using saveAndFlush(...) did the trick

Comment: this, TIL save doesn't necessarily save changes immediately to the database, flush however synchronizes the entity with the database.

Answer (score 2):

Just to reinforce: **`java.util.Calender` is not for Timestamps**.  `java.util.Date` is for a moment in time, agnostic of regional things like timezones.  Most database store things in this fashion (even if they appear not to; this is usually a timezone setting in the client software; the data is good)

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is to have a common base class for all your entities. In this base class, you can have your id property if it is commonly named in all your entities (a common design), your creation and last update date properties.

For the creation date, you simply keep a *java.util.Date* property. Be sure, to always initialize it with *new Date()*.

For the last update field, you can use a Timestamp property, you need to map it with @Version. With this Annotation the property will get updated automatically by Hibernate. Beware that Hibernate will also apply optimistic locking (it's a good thing).

Comment: using a timestamp column for optimistic locking is a bad idea. Always use an integer version column. Reason being, 2 JVMs might be on different times and might not have millisecond accuracy. If you instead make hibernate use the DB timestamp, that would mean additional selects from the DB. Instead just use version number.

Answer (score 1):

As data type in JAVA I strongly recommend to use java.util.Date. I ran into pretty nasty timezone problems when using Calendar. See this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82235/is-there-a-problem-with-jpa-entities-oracle-10g-and-calendar-type-properties).

For setting the timestamps I would recommend using either an AOP approach or you could simply use Triggers on the table (actually this is the only thing that I ever find the use of triggers acceptable).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider storing the time as a DateTime, and in UTC. I typically use DateTime instead of Timestamp because of the fact that MySql converts dates to UTC and back to local time when storing and retrieving the data. I'd rather keep any of that kind of logic in one place (Business layer). I'm sure there are other situations where using Timestamp is preferable though.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation. We were using Mysql 5.7.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
        ...
      updated_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
```

This worked for us.

Comment: It also works in a case when the data is modified by a SQL query directly in the database. `@PrePersist` and `@PrePersist` don't cover such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is neater not doing this in Java code, you can simply set column default value in MySql table definition.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version with `Spring Boot 3.1.1` and `Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final`

My answer will be usefull if you want more controle on preInsert and preUpdate operation with more logic, could be anything, here I'm also adding the username

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(CustomEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION", updatable = false)
    private Date dateCreation;

    @Column(name = "USER_CREATION", updatable = false)
    private String userCreation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATE_UPDATE", nullable = true, insertable = false)
    private Date dateUpdate;

    @Column(name = "USER_UPDATE", nullable = true, insertable = false)
    private String userUpdate;
```

All your entity could extend this

Then create your CustomEntityListener

```
import jakarta.persistence.PrePersist;
import jakarta.persistence.PreUpdate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class CustomEntityListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomEntityListener.class);
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Object entity) {
        if (entity instanceof AbstractEntity) {
            setUsernameCreation((AbstractEntity) entity);
            setDateCreation((AbstractEntity) entity);
        }
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Object entity) {
        if (entity instanceof AbstractEntity) {
            setUsernameUpdate((AbstractEntity) entity);
            setDateUpdate((AbstractEntity) entity);
        }
    }

    private void setDateCreation(AbstractEntity entity) {
        entity.setDateCreation(new Date());
    }

    private void setDateUpdate(AbstractEntity entity) {
        entity.setDateUpdate(new Date());
    }

    private void setUsernameCreation(AbstractEntity entity) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            String username = authentication.getName();
            entity.setUserCreation(username);
        }
    }
    private void setUsernameUpdate(AbstractEntity entity) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            String username = authentication.getName();
            entity.setUserUpdate(username);
        }
    }
```

You also need for your Listener to be loaded this class `JpaConfig`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class JpaConfig {
    // Required by CustomEntityListener
}
```