# @PreUpdate and @Prepersist in hibernate/JPA (using session)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I've hit a blocker adding a fix to an existing project.the main problem is that i'll like to use `@Prepersist` and `@PreUpdate` in the `POJO` to take care of `LastModified` field (insert and update) using hibernate implementation of JPA with session.

***Reason ?***:
That change is required because there is a need to use `liquibase 1.9.5` and i know (since i've faced this before) that liquibase translate timestamp fied to datetime with default current_timestamp, and that is too bad for mysql database.

So i needed a way to have this set in code rather than in database so i could safely change timestamp field to datetime.then liquibase is happy, i'm happy.

Now it seems that those interpreters are not been executed, with little search i found out that it's suitable using `entityManager`.That is currently out of question.So i'll like to know if is there a **SIMPLE** way around my problem, meaning having `@Prepersist` or `@PreUpdate` or even other workaround to set the `lastModified` field still using session

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> Now it seems that those interpreters are not been executed, with little search i found out that it's suitable using entityManager.

Yes, the JPA callbacks won't work if you're using the `Session` API.

> So I'll like to know if is there a SIMPLE way around my problem, meaning having @PrePersist or @PreUpdate or even other workaround to set the lastModified field still using session

To my knowledge, there is no simple way around (if you're using Spring, *MAYBE* have a look at [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=54566) though).

My suggestion for an Hibernate based solution would be to use [events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) (and one or more interface(s)). Check [Hibernate and last modified date](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/03/hibernate-using-event-listener-to-set.html) for an example.

Comment: Hi Pascal, i've tried using the hibernate event listener and it worked.thanks again for your help. ;)

Comment: There is a very good explanation of listeners at [http://anshuiitk.blogspot.sk/2010/11/hibernate-pre-database-opertaion-event.html](http://anshuiitk.blogspot.sk/2010/11/hibernate-pre-database-opertaion-event.html)

Comment: Here's an easy way to enable the necessary event listeners: https://n1njahacks.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/jpa-callbacks-with-hibernates-sessionfactory-and-no-entitymanager/

Answer (score 0):

Mainly @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations are used in entity in hibernate or jpa. When we save an entity on that time  @PrePersist method is called.