# Hibernate SessionFactory vs. JPA EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sessionfactory, hibernate-entitymanager

I am new to Hibernate and I'm not sure whether to use a Hibernate `SessionFactory` or a JPA `EntityManagerFactory` to create a Hibernate `Session`.

What is the difference between these two?  What are the pros & cons of using each of those?

Comment: This answer on a duplicated question is really good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445830/hibernate-sessionfactory-vs-entitymanagerfactory#answer-23446379

Answer (score 425, accepted):

Prefer `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`. They are defined by the JPA standard.

`SessionFactory` and `Session` are hibernate-specific. The `EntityManager` invokes the hibernate session under the hood. And if you need some specific features that are not available in the `EntityManager`, you can obtain the session by calling:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Comment: You are a wealth of knowledge!  I am just starting out with Hibernate and would like to use Hibernate with JPA Annotations - would you recommend any good resources for a beginner (besides the Hibernate documentation)?

Comment: @elpisu - I can't recommend, actually. I've been using only the official documentation as a learning resource (at least in the past 2 years), so I don't know anything else reliable. But the docs are good enough.

Comment: @Bozho I know that it's late but what are the drawbacks of using SessionFactory and Session? Why the use of JPA is preferred? Thanks

Comment: @Bozho please can you elaborate, i also want to know why especially when spring to kinda of going entitymanager with its new `spring-data-jpa` which uses.What are the drawbacks on sessionFactory.THanks

Comment: Oh sorry, what i mean is data spring-data-jpa is going entityManager way when it comes to hibernate persistence vendor.I wanted to know if that is a significant clue as for going entityManager way as opposed to session way.Thanks

Comment: @MickaelMarrache the use of the JPA is to be preferred over the Hibernate API, because it is a Java Enterprise standard. Using JPA (and restricting yourself to it, without using Hibernate-specific features) improves application portability, i.e. you have the option to switch to a different persistence framework with minimal changes to your application, as long as that framework also conforms to the JPA standard.

Comment: is it possible to programmatically construct HQL queries using only JPA-covered functionality?

Comment: Is it better just because it's an enterprise standard? I doubt that. Standards are usually slow to evolve and complicated. What about some real life benefits? JPA is better because it has TypedQuery, stops you from typecasting all over the place.

Comment: Is this approach to get `Session` from `EntityManager`, same as `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`? I mean, will it open new `Session` if it is not already created? How does it work in multithreaded environment?

Answer (score 81):

### `SessionFactory` vs. `EntityManagerFactory`

As I explained in the [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html), the Hibernate `SessionFactory` extends the JPA `EntityManagerFactory`, as illustrated by the following diagram:

[image: JPA and Hibernate relationship]

So, the `SessionFactory` is also a JPA `EntityManagerFactory`.

Both the `SessionFactory` and the `EntityManagerFactory` contain the entity mapping metadata and allow you to create a Hibernate `Session` or a `EntityManager`.

### `Session` vs. `EntityManager`

Just like the `SessionFactory` and `EntityManagerFactory`, the Hibernate `Session` extends the JPA `EntityManager`. So, all methods defined by the `EntityManager` are available in the Hibernate `Session`.

The `Session` and the `EntityManager translate [entity state transitions](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/) into SQL statements, like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE.

### Hibernate vs. JPA bootstrap

When bootstrapping a JPA or Hibernate application, you have two choices:

1. You can bootstrap via the Hibernate native mechanism, and create a `SessionFactory` via the [`BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/util/AbstractTest.java#L147). If you're using Spring, the Hibernate bootstrap is done via the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, as illustrated by [this GitHub example](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-optimizer/blob/master/hypersistence-optimizer-spring-hibernate-example/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/optimizer/config/HibernateTransactionManagerConfiguration.java#L70).
2. Or, you can create a JPA `EntityManagerFactory` via the [`Persistence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) class or the [`EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-hibernate-without-the-persistence-xml-file/). If you're using Spring, the JPA bootstrap is done via the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, as illustrated by [this GitHub example](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-optimizer/blob/master/hypersistence-optimizer-spring-jpa-example/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/optimizer/jpa/JpaTransactionManagerConfiguration.java#L73).

Bootstrapping via JPA is to be preferred. That's because the JPA `FlushModeType.AUTO` is a much better choice than the legacy `FlushMode.AUTO`, which [breaks read-your-writes consistency for native SQL queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-jpa-and-hibernate-define-the-auto-flush-mode/).

### Unwrapping JPA to Hibernate

Also, if you bootstrap via JPA, and you have injected the `EntityManagerFactory` via the `@PersistenceUnit` annotation:

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

You can easily get access to the underlying `Sessionfactory` using the `unwrap` method:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

The same can be done with the JPA `EntityManager`. If you inject the `EntityManager` via the `@PersistenceContext` annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

You can easily get access to the underlying `Session` using the `unwrap` method:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

### Conclusion

So, you should bootstrap via JPA, use the `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`, and only unwrap those to their associated Hibernate interfaces when you want to get access to some Hibernate-specific methods that are not available in JPA, like fetching the entity via its [natural identifier](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-naturalid-business-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Answer (score 32):

I want to add on this that you can also get Hibernate's session by calling `getDelegate()` method from `EntityManager`.

ex:

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
```

Comment: note that `unwrap()` is **to be preferred** over `getDelegate()` according to the java docs: [javaee 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate()), and [javaee 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate()).

Answer (score 25):

I prefer the JPA2 `EntityManager` API over `SessionFactory`, because it feels more modern. One simple example:

JPA:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public List<MyEntity> findSomeApples() {
  return entityManager
     .createQuery("from MyEntity where apples=7", MyEntity.class)
     .getResultList();
}
```

SessionFactory:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<MyEntity> findSomeApples() {
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  List<?> result = session.createQuery("from MyEntity where apples=7")
      .list();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<MyEntity> resultCasted = (List<MyEntity>) result;
  return resultCasted;
}
```

I think it's clear that the first one looks cleaner and is also easier to test because EntityManager can be easily mocked.

Comment: You can make any code complicated if you want. `return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where id=1").list()`

Comment: How directly you got entityManager and you are showing you have to use sessionfactory to fetch session.. :D

Answer (score 23):

Using EntityManagerFactory approach  allows us to use callback method annotations like @PrePersist, @PostPersist,@PreUpdate with no extra configuration.

Using similar callbacks while using SessionFactory will require extra efforts.

Related Hibernate docs can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-interceptors) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/class-use/EventType.html).

[Related SOF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133287/preupdate-and-prepersist-in-hibernate-jpa-using-session#answer-4133629) and [Spring Forum discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?54566-Hibernate-3-2-Persistent-Lifecycle-annotations-not-work)

Answer (score 3):

EntityManagerFactory is the standard implementation, it is the same across all the implementations. If you migrate your ORM for any other provider like EclipseLink, there will not be any change in the approach for handling the transaction. In contrast, if you use hibernate’s session factory, it is tied to hibernate APIs and cannot migrate to new vendor.

Answer (score 2):

By using EntityManager, code is no longer tightly coupled with hibernate. But for this, in usage we should use :

```
javax.persistence.EntityManager
```

instead of

```
org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager
```

Similarly, for EntityManagerFactory, use javax interface. That way, the code is loosely coupled. If there is a better JPA 2 implementation than hibernate, switching would be easy. In extreme case, we could type cast to HibernateEntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

EntityManager  interface is similar to  sessionFactory in  hibernate.
EntityManager under javax.persistance package  but session and sessionFactory under org.hibernate.Session/sessionFactory package.

Entity manager is JPA specific and session/sessionFactory are hibernate specific.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but is essentially the same as the answer Sangyun Lee refers to in his comments... so a duplicate.

Comment: SessionFactory ~= EntityManagerFactory, and NOT EntityManager. Wrong answer.