# MySQL EntityManager Range Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

How can i simplify this Query, to run it only once.
My current code:

```
    int year = 2014;

    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT   SUM(s.revenue),SUM(s.mediaSpending),SUM(s.grossProfit) FROM Sale s WHERE YEAR(s.date) = :year AND QUARTER(s.date) = :quarter");
    q.setParameter("year", year);

    q.setParameter("quarter", 1);
    Object[] q1 = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();

    q.setParameter("quarter", 2);
    Object[] q2 = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();

    q.setParameter("quarter", 3);
    Object[] q3 = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();

    q.setParameter("quarter", 4);
    Object[] q4 = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();
```

can i somehow query a list for all 4 qartal at once ?
Something like this:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT   SUM(s.revenue),SUM(s.mediaSpending),SUM(s.grossProfit) FROM Sale s WHERE YEAR(s.date) = :year AND QUARTER(s.date) =  ???(1-4)");

List<Object[]> q1 =  q.getResultList();
```

EDIT:
The result should be a list of 4 Object :

```
List{Q1Statistic, Q2Statistic, Q3Statistic, Q4Statistic}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can try following code

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT SUM(s.revenue),SUM(s.mediaSpending),SUM(s.grossProfit) FROM Sale s WHERE YEAR(s.date) = :year AND QUARTER(s.date) = :quarter");
query.setParameter("year", year);
query.setParameter("quarter", 1);
List<Object[]> result = query.list();
```

also have a look at [Hibernate SessionFactory vs. EntityManagerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640778/hibernate-sessionfactory-vs-entitymanagerfactory)

***EDIT***

It seams like the issue is in your Query try following query hope this help you

***QUERY***

```
SELECT SUM(s.revenue),SUM(s.mediaSpending),SUM(s.grossProfit) FROM Sale s 
WHERE YEAR(s.date) = :year 
GROUP BY YEAR(s.date) , QUARTER(s.date)
```