# JPA Error- No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I can't solve this problem at all and there are a ton of stack overflow posts with this exact same error message. I have tried them all and I still can't get it to work. Maybe I am over looking something small. I really need help with this and thank you in advance.

Error Message

```
Initial EntityManagerFactory creation failed.javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at util.DatabaseUtil.buildSessionFactory(DatabaseUtil.java:18)
    at util.DatabaseUtil.<clinit>(DatabaseUtil.java:8)
    at Test.main(Test.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at util.DatabaseUtil.buildSessionFactory(DatabaseUtil.java:13)
    ... 7 more
```

Directory Structure please ignore the hibernate.cfg.xml file, I tried using hibernate sessionFactory and ran into a major error I couldn't solve as well and said the hell with it. Plus this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445830/hibernate-sessionfactory-vs-entitymanagerfactory) says JPA is preferred
[image]

Here are the needed jar files
[image]

Here is the persistence.xml file

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

  <persistence-unit name="com.learning.jpa">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>com.learning.jpa.entities.User</class>
    <class>com.learning.jpa.entities.Expense</class>
    <class>com.learning.jpa.entities.Category</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="1"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/budget_calculator"/>
        <property name="hibernate.onnection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>    
    </properties>        
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

EntityManagerFactory

```
public class DatabaseUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static EntityManagerFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                sessionFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");
            }
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial EntityManagerFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong identifier for your Persistence-Unit. The name of it is specified here:

```
...
  <persistence-unit name="com.learning.jpa">
  ...
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The StackTrace tells you

> No Persistence provider for EntityManager named *org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence*

So you need to reference the PU via its correct, given name *com.learning.jpa* in the relevant code snippet like so:

```
if (sessionFactory == null) {
    sessionFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.learning.jpa"); 
}
```

Having changed to the correct PU-name it should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you this fixed the problem. I tried this before, actually this is what I had initially but I must have overlooked the error and thought it was the same error because this generates a new error. I didn't try this when I moved the project to IntelliJ from Eclipse. Im going to give the new error a shot and see what I can do, thats how you learn sometimes.