# Hibernate don't work in CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to make a simple hibernate application and when I am trying to run it using usual java class it works well, but when I am trying to run it using `CommandLineRunner` using Spring Boot it fails with an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection : [class springboottest.entity.Item.id] setter of springboottest.entity.Item.id
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field springboottest.entity.Item.id to springboottest.entity.Item
```

when `session.save(item1);` executed.
`CommandLineRunner` works well, for example

```
@Service
public class DBInit implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Override
    public void run(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("woring");
    }
}
```

prints "working" as expected.
`Hibernate` also works well if used with normal `java` class with `main()`, but `Hibernate` don't working inside `run()` in `CommandLineRunner`.
I don't use none of `Spring Boot` features here like dependency injection or something else, just plain `java` code.
So why I have an error and how to make it work?

```java
// don't working
@Service
public class DBInit implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Override
    public void run(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Item.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession())
        {
            Item item1 = new Item("itemName");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(item1);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
// working well
public class DBInit
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Item.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession())
        {
            Item item1 = new Item("itemName");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(item1);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
         }
    }
}
```

Item class

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Item
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int id;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    public Item(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="springboottest.entity.Item"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Comment: @özkanpakdil https://github.com/Denys-coder/Hibernate_dont_work_in_CommandLineRunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is mixing "old style" and spring boot. When DBInit.main runs without spring, it creates `SessionFactory` and when spring boot **CommandLineRunner** runs spring initialize `EntityManagerFactory` that provides all `sessions` after.

The difference is "sessionFactory" uses "hibernate.cfg.xml" it already has `<mapping class="springboottest.entity.Item"/>` therefore it works as expected, but **EntityManagerFactory** does not use *hibernate.cfg.xml*, so **mapping** is broken. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5640778/175554) for more details.

How to solve it, for spring you should use **@Repository**. [The blog](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and here is the solution

```
package springboottest.entity;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository  extends CrudRepository<Item, Integer> {
}
```

and DBinit service should be like below

```
@Service
public class DBInit implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Autowired
    ItemRepository repo;

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("CommandLineRunner run() executing...");
        repo.save(new Item("ItemName"));
    }
}
```

cfg xml is not required and add properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format-sql=true
```

that will make spring work properly.

PR: https://github.com/Denys-coder/Hibernate_dont_work_in_CommandLineRunner/pull/1

[my repo](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/Hibernate_dont_work_in_CommandLineRunner/tree/fix-hibernate)