# How to persist multiple new entity instances belonging to one common entity instance in one go

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

There are 2 related entities in a *Hibernate JPA* project:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="order_sequence", strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="orderitem_sequence", strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Order order;
    //....
}
```

With some detailed code ignored, I tried to merge a new `Order` instance with a `List` of `OrderItem` instances in *cascade* manner, i.e. `merge` the `List<OrderItem>` with an `EntityManager` - "em" in one go without `merge` the new `Order`:

```
for (OrderItem orderItem: orderItemList) {
    em.merge(orderItem);
}
```

But encountered error when the size of the `List<OrderItem>` is greater than 1: `Unique index or primary key violation` since the same `Order` is merged multiple times when merging each `Order` instance.

**Question: How to resolve this error without merge the Order instance explicitly as a separate `merge`?**

Comment: Does the `Order` have a list of `OrderItem`s as field? If yes, why not just merge the `Order`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer No, only the `OrderItem` has dependency on the `Order`, not the other way around, so it is a unidirectional dependency relatioship

Comment: According to [this website](https://www.coderscampus.com/hibernate-manytoone-unidirectional-tutorial/), you could try to save instead of merging. This would force you to manage the insert or update yourself

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thanks a lot first for the tip. But the link you sent used the ``hibernate.SessionFactory`, so do it mean that by using `EntityManager`, I would be forced to avoid using `CascadeType.ALL` and then insert `Order` and list of `OrderItem`s separately?

Comment: [There is no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640796/7109162). `EntityManager` and `SessionFactory` work basically the same. It seems to come down to what method you call. For `EntityManager` you would probably call `persist()` method instead of the `merge()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Did you see the error, `Unique index or primary key violation`, I mentioned in the question? So does it mean that this error is caused by the call on `merge()` and using `persist()` will prevent this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Indeed I tried to use `persist()` instead of `merge()` and it works :) Thanks a lot. So if you answer it, I would confirm the correctness