# How to auto generate the timestamp in a entity bean in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How does one auto generate the timestamp in a entity bean in hibernate?

Does the `@Generator` have anything to directly put in it like:

```
@GeneratedValue(vale=new Date().getTime())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement global EntityInterceptor:

```
public class GlobalEntityInterceptor 
    extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean onSave(java.lang.Object entity, java.io.Serializable p2, java.lang.Object[] p3, java.lang.String[] p4, org.hibernate.type.Type[] p5) {   
  //first save - you can modify your entity fields
}
    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(java.lang.Object entity, java.io.Serializable p2, java.lang.Object[] p3, java.lang.Object[] p4, java.lang.String[] p5, 
                                    org.hibernate.type.Type[] p6) { 
  //modification  - you can modify your entity fields 

}
```

there are some annotation-driven solutions like **@PrePersist**, but they only work in few [environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133287/preupdate-and-prepersist-in-hibernate-jpa-using-session).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put some code into the annotation, you just provide the values.

For automatically updating a timestamp at every change to the entity, you can use @Version on a timestamp field:

```
   @Version
   private Timestamp lastUpdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use hibernates interceptors for populating entities with some data ie. creation date etc.

Read here for more information about [interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors)

Comment: I was very tempted to down vote you :) you answer is horrible