# JPA not creating columns when using @PrePersist & @PreUpdate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am attempting to resolve the same old issue with having a reusable set of Created and Updated time stamp fields.  I have attempted to implement this solution: [using @PrePersist and @PreUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4038363) with no success.

When I try this approach the created and updated columns are not created in the table. Extending the `AbstractTimestampEntity` class has no effect on the table creation.  The only way I get the columns created is by using the generally accepted approach of using private member variables with public getter/setter methods which have the standard annotations `@Column(nullable=false)` and `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`.

I assumed (yeah, I know) that extending the `AbstractTimestampEntity` class and the annotations within it would cause my `SchemaExport(config)`.create call to include the two inherited fields and create the columns.

Fairly certain that I'm missing something simple (yet not obvious).  Are there overrides for the two fields that need to exist in the entity model class?

btw - I'm using `hibernate-distribution-3.6.8.Final, hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA and db-derby-10.8.2.2-bin`.