# How to auto insert Current DATE in SQL with Java / Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, date, annotations

I need to add automatically the current date into my Database when I create a new OperantionBank.
I'm using Hibernate.
Thanks

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime;

@Entity
public class OperationBank implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String wordring;

private Double amount;

@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateoperation = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());

@OneToOne
private Account account;
```

Comment: so, what happens when you run the above code?Did it work? Post the logs if you are getting any exceptions.

Comment: there is no exceptions but the col "date" in my sqldatabase is filled by NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer might help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/221827/355499

In essence you use `@PrePersist` and/or `@PreUpdate` annotation to generate the dates when needed.

Answer (score 5):

While *Emil H* is correct, I would like to add that way you did should work too.

It didn't most likely because the name of the column (you said in comment it is "date") doesn't match name of the field ("dateoperation").

You could either rename field/column, or add annotation:

```
@Column(name = "date")
```

Also note: you don't have to use *java.sql.Date*, it should work with *java.util.Date* just as well.

```
import java.util.Date;
...

@Column(name = "date")
private Date dateoperation = new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

For create, you need to use:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateoperation = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
@CreatedDate
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "start_date")
private Date startDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this as input 2004-05-19

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

private Calendar tryMe;