# how to make mysql automatically update column to current timestamp on every modify row operation?

Tags: java, mysql

there are 2 columns in my mysql table: created_on and modified_on.I have set the default value for created_on column to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. thus on every insert operation in the table the created_on column correctly sets the value to current timestamp.however i want that when i update the same row the 'modified_on' column updates the value to the timestamp when it is updated.Let me know if i use any function/trigger to do so or is there any in-build mysql feature for the same

Comment: use trigger to update automatically

Comment: Are you using any ORM framework?

Comment: i am using hibernate 3.0

Comment: @user1767274 maybe you find this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221611/creation-timestamp-and-last-update-timestamp-with-hibernate-and-mysql

Comment: and i suggest do not use triggers, because it always adds some 'magic'.

Answer (score 4):

Try alter your table with `ON UPDATE` keyword like:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` 
CHANGE `modified_on` `modified_on` TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Or you can add default value when inserted like:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` 
CHANGE `modified_on` `modified_on` TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

You also can define `ON UPDATE` to a timestamp data type when you create a table.

Answer (score 1):

Write a trigger for doing this