# Set LocalDateTime to autogenerate with hibernate 4.3.10

Tags: java, hibernate, time

Currently I have a base entity as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private boolean deleted;

    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Is it possible to annotate `LocalDateTime` with something to make database default to current date and time?

p.s. I am not allowed to use hibernate 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the @PrePersist annotation.

> Executed before the entity manager persist operation is actually
>   executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the persist
>   operation.

Example:

```
  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    createdAt = new LocalDateTime();
    updatedAt = new LocalDateTime();
  }
```

And if you deem it fit you also have available the @PreUpdate annotation.

Read more on [events that occur inside hibernate's persistence mechanism](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html)

Answer (score 0):

@LaurentiuL is correct.
 But I think below should also work

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime createdAt = new LocalDateTime ();
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime updatedAt= new LocalDateTime ();
```

Also answers of this question should help you : [Creation timestamp and last update timestamp with Hibernate and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221611/creation-timestamp-and-last-update-timestamp-with-hibernate-and-mysql)

Comment: @Nomad ohh.. yes thats right.. In that case the answers at said questions should work..