# How to generate epoch timestamp for audit fields in hibernate entity?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have created an abstract entity class to have only audit fields viz. createdDate and modifiedDate. I want hibernate to automatically generate values for these fields of type `java.lang.Long` when respective queries are fired.

I am trying to use `@CreationTimestamp` (org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp) but spring complains with following--

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unsupported property type for generator annotation @CreationTimestamp

I have also tried `@Temporal` but that does not work with fields of type `Long`. I don't want to store date in `java.util.Date` type.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA you can do it like this

```
private Long createdDate;
private Long updatedDate;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    createdDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    updatedDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    updatedDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Having said that why don't you want an updatedDate to be a Date???  I would think about making it a Date, not a Long.

See [Creation timestamp and last update timestamp with Hibernate and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221611/creation-timestamp-and-last-update-timestamp-with-hibernate-and-mysql)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I had already this seen this solution however I am using Session and not EntityManager. I want something that executes on `Session#save` and `Session#merge`