# why onFlushDirty detects address as dirty but not contact in EmptyInterceptor

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Contact Interceptor attached with hibernate configuration

```
public class ContactInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    /**
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2000639365689865828L;

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        if (entity instanceof LastModifiable) {
            if (!Arrays.equals(currentState, previousState)) {
                int index = ArrayUtils.indexOf(propertyNames, "modified");
                if (index > 0) {
                    currentState[index] = new Date();
                    return super.onFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Address model

```
public class Address extends Model {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long              id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "contact_id")
    private Contact           contact;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String            address1;

    @Column(name = "address2")
    private String            address2;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String            city;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String            country;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String            state;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String            zipcode;

    @Column(name = "company")
    private String            company;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long val) {
        this.id=val;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.modified = this.created = created;
    }

    private Date created = null;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modified", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    public Date getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(Date modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    private Date modified;

}
```

Contact.java

```
public  class Contact extends Model {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long              id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String            firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String            lastName;

    @Transient
    private String            fullName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String            email;

    @Column(name = "contact")
    private String            contact;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Set<Address>    addresses        = new HashSet<Address>(0);

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
        public Date getCreated() {
            return created;
        }

        public void setCreated(Date created) {
            this.modified = this.created = created;
        }

        private Date created = null;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "modified", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
        public Date getModified() {
            return modified;
        }

        public void setModified(Date modified) {
            this.modified = modified;
        }

        private Date modified;


}
```

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateUtility u = new HibernateUtility();
        u.beginTransaction();

        Contact c = DBService.getDBService(Contact.class).load(112L);

        Address add = new Address();
        add.setAddress1("Dummy Address 1");
        add.setCity("AHMD");
        add.setState("GUJ");
        add.setCreated(new Date());
        add.setCountry("INR");
        add.setContact(c);
        c.getAddresses().add(add);
//        c.setModified(new Date());

        u.endTransaction();
    }
```

As we know that onFlushDirty is **Called when an object is detected to be dirty** [jboss Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onFlushDirty(java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[]))

But when I add address in in Contact which has type collection, during debug I can see address is dirty (as new record is going to insert) but why contact is not dirty here ?

**Does hibernate don't detect dirty object in case of collection modification ? or am I missing something ?**

My Primary Concern is **when Child is dirty or modified parent modified date should also be change**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirty objects are ones that get saved/updated on flush, not the objects that are associated with them. Otherwise all objects associated with `Contact`s should also be considered dirty because the contacts that they contain have "changed", then all objects associated with those objects etc. effectively meaning that a large portion of the database could get considered dirty because you add a new address.

The only solution is to manually write the logic that executes when associated objects change, as Hibernate cannot know an application's specific business rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to call em.persist(address), dirty checking works just for managed entities.
2. Didn't you forget to add hibernate.ejb.interceptor.session_scoped=package.ContactInterceptor property??
3. to manage modified and created date just use @CreationTimestamp, @UpdateTimestamp and Hibernate does the magic for you :)
   see [Creation timestamp and last update timestamp with Hibernate and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221611/creation-timestamp-and-last-update-timestamp-with-hibernate-and-mysql/39427923#39427923)

Comment: @UpdateTimestamp works only when I change anything in Contact.java entity but if I'm adding new address, it is not modifying Contact

Comment: agree, you should do it manually, like add method that changes modified date for address entity.

Comment: definitely manual is the worst case scenario. What I want here is to have single controller to manage such event. Is there a way to check whether Object is dirty in DefaultSaveOrUpdaeEvent ?

Comment: @SantoshGiri Actually you can catch it in public void onCollectionUpdate(Object collection, Serializable key) in Interceptor. When you add a new address to contact's address you will be able to handle it as you wish.